# Not able to authenticate to SharePoint online using PNP POwerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a script which is working on Windows server 2012 r2, by this script is download excel file from SharePoint online and save it in file server. But now i have to migrate this script to new windows server 2016, and it is failing there, when i try to do Connect_pnponline -url, I get error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI02O.png)

I have installed SharePoint Online module, Not sure why it is not working on new server, Is there any initial set up i have to do.

Comment: The error message says exactly what you have to do.

Comment: @marsze When i do, what error message says, i get this error.- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"